# std::future::wait_for returns immediately timeout while the time duration has not elapsed

Tags: c++, c++17, future, std-future

I have encountered an issue related to `std::async` and `std::future::wait_for`.
I have the following code

```
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){return myfunction();});

auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
if (status == std::future_status::ready)
{
    auto result = future.get();
    std::cout << "result is " << result << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << (status == std::future_status::timeout ? "timeout" : "deferred") << std::endl;
}
```

It is running on x86_64 GNU/Linux (The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0).
Most of the time, this piece of code works well.
However, occasionally(I only meet once), future.wait_for returned timeout immediately without waiting even if timeout_duration is set to 5seconds.

According to [text](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for), wait_for should return timeout only if timeout_duration has elapsed.

So far, I have no idea why future.wait_for returned timeout immediately without waiting occasionally.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: Kindly post a [mcve].

Comment: You need to include compiler and probably OS here.  Define occassionally as well; we talking "I have proof it happened in ablog after billions of uses", or "it happens every 10 tests"?

Comment: Documented behavior : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for. I probably would use condition variables and pass a timeout value to myFunction (and let it throw if it times out or gets cancelled) instead anyway.

Comment: (As an example, at least one compiler implemented wait for with wait until, and clock changes can lead to spurious timeouts: but the information provided doesn't let me rule that in or out as a possible cause)

Comment: *" if timeout_duration is set to 5seconds"* But the timeout is set to 5 milliseconds.

Comment: It is running on x86_64 GNU/Linux (The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0)
Regarding definition of occassionally, I only met once out of 44 tests

Comment: @YakkAdamNevraumont, I was wondering if this issue is related to clock change. https://docs.w3cub.com/cpp/thread/future/wait_for says *The standard recommends that a steady clock is used to measure the duration. If an implementation uses a system clock instead, the wait time may also be sensitive to clock adjustments.*

I am a bit confused about above statement.

As the input parameter of future::wait_for is a duration, who is responsible to choose  a steady clock or a system clock?